# How to set visibility gone from another class to textview and imageview that belong to activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, fingerprint

I am trying to set a visibility value to certainviews in my activity. The problem is that I don't see any changes.

In my Login activity I have the option for the user to Login with fingerprint. When the user has the option to login with fingerprint my activity hiddes the EditText and shows an imageview when the actyvity is created. What I want to do is in case the user fails the fingerprint login 3 times in a row the activity should hide an image view and show an Edittext so that he can login with password.

Inside my main activity I have this method:

```
public void ChangeViews(Context context){
    LinearLayout passwoordInsert;
    ImageView enterBtnMasked;
    ImageView imgFinger;
    TextView txtFinger;

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_masked_login, null);
    passwoordInsert = vi.findViewById(R.id.password_insert_f);
    enterBtnMasked = vi.findViewById(R.id.enter_btn_masked_f);
    imgFinger=vi.findViewById(R.id.fingerprintImage_f);
    txtFinger=vi.findViewById(R.id.text_fnger_f);

    passwoordInsert.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    enterBtnMasked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    txtFinger.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    imgFinger.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    Log.e("IsDataChanged", "Data is changed");


}
```

The method above is called inside my FingerPrintHandler.class after showing an alertDialog:

```
 @Override
public void onAuthenticationFailed() {

CancelAuth();
setAlert("Retry writting your password");
}
```

AlertDialog called when the user fails for 3 times in a row, this method is inside my fingerprinthandler class:

```
public void setAlert(String message) {
    alertDialog = new SweetAlertDialog(context, SweetAlertDialog.WARNING_TYPE);
    alertDialog.setTitleText("Error");
    alertDialog.setContentText(message);
    alertDialog.setConfirmText("Aceptar");
    alertDialog.setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sweetAlertDialog) {

            alertDialog.dismissWithAnimation();

            MaskedLogin maskedLogin = new MaskedLogin();
            maskedLogin.ChangeViews(context);


        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

I've been trying to achieve this for hours but no success yet. Any suggestion would be apreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a callback to communicate between `YourActivity` and `YourHandler` class,

example:

In `YourHandler`, create an interface

```
public interface ChangeViewListener {
    void onViewChanged();
}

private ChangeViewListener listener;


public void setAlert(String message) {
    alertDialog = new SweetAlertDialog(context, SweetAlertDialog.WARNING_TYPE);
    alertDialog.setTitleText("Error");
    alertDialog.setContentText(message);
    alertDialog.setConfirmText("Aceptar");
    alertDialog.setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sweetAlertDialog) {

            if(listener != null) {
               listener.onViewChanged();
            }


        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();
}

public void setListener(ChangeViewListener listener) {
   this.listener = listener;
}
```

and finally, call setListener in `yourActivity`

```
yourHandler.setlistener(YourActivity.this)
```

of course, implement this listener in your activity

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements YourHandler.ViewChangeListener {
...
override void onViewChanged() {
  // call method ChangeViews here
}
...
}
```

that is a right approach in your case! hope it helps

Comment: Beautiful, thanks a lot @GianhTan, this worked for me!

Comment: @LuisAguilar nice to help you

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem

```
MaskedLogin maskedLogin = new MaskedLogin();
maskedLogin.ChangeViews();
```

What this does is to create a new instace of the `MaskedLogin` activity that is different from the one currently on your screen, so you're calling the `ChangeViews` property of an off-screen object.

I'm not sure how your project structure is set, but you should try to keep a reference to the Context/activity so you can call `ChangeViews` on the correct Object.

Comment: I got you!! Let me try this and see what happens!! I have to pass the context to the fingerprint handler and call the changeviews method sending that same context.